# Can I set priority for certain start-up services?

Tags: macos

I've set up a Synergy client on my copy of Lion. I have configured it to auto-start on login and for my computer to auto-login. However, it takes about 2-3 minutes for the Synergy service to finally run and connect to my Windows server. Is there any way to set the priority of this service?

Comment: I see that launch daemons can have a HopefullyExitsFirst / HopefullyExitsLast setting... but this is the opposite of what you want :)

Comment: Is it the synergy service *starting* that is taking so long, or is it the *network connection*? I know on my setup, if I start the client first, it connects almost instantaneously. If I start the server, it sometimes takes as much as 30 seconds, because the client has timed out, and only retries to connect every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Check the logs (Console.app) to find out what is really causing the delay on startup. It may be spawning rapidly because the network isn't up yet and then getting throttled by launchd, causing the delay. The logs will tell you what's going on. If this is the problem, launchd has an option to wait for the network (KeepAlive > NetworkState).